# How would I encapsulate/encode mutliple boolean values in Hibernate outside of the entity and maybe save memory?

Tags: hibernate

Not sure if my title is the best but what I'm having is an `@Entity` that has some basic attributes like `String name` or `String description` and so on.

But is also needs *a lot* (there are 18 to be exact) of `Boolean` type variables:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

// Here comes the nasty stuff:

@Column(name="ATTR1")
private Boolean attr1;

@Column(name="ATTR2")
private Boolean attr2;

@Column(name="ATTR3")
private Boolean attr3;

@Column(name="ATTR4")
private Boolean attr4;

// and so on ..
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to store a larger amount of  `Boolean` variables in another object that wraps up those booleans and is part of my `@Entity`?

In addition I would like to know if I can somehow tell `Hibernate` to save some memory. It would make a difference if I'd save *18 * sizeof(Boolean)* bytes or just one int that holds the boolean values for me of course.

So, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you (or whoever did the model for that table/entity) may have something not quite right. Those are attributes and eventually you might want to store them as a key/value pair (in a `Map`, for instance).

I'm not sure why are you so much concerned about "saving memory"; it's cheap these days, but that doesn't means you can get to whatever model you want just because you can store anything...they don't relate and, if you fix one, you will be fixing the other.

Anyway, it's hard to change anything if you can't change the database itself.

Comment: Hi! Why would I want to store those in a key/value map? Instead of `getA()` I would have to somehow manage that my clients know about the keys `object.get(key)` which is more complicated imho. Is there a reason why you're suggesting that? Regarding the memory consumption you're absolutely right. I guess it doesn't pay off to save a few bytes per entry compared to maintainability in this case.

Comment: Well, the reason is because you have, for instance, 18 things...and that's what makes sense, at least for me. Another analogy: what if you have to store many books? You would use a `List` or `Set`; in the same way, the attributes "looks like" a one-to-many relationship (but assuming you cannot use another table) then it makes sense to have them in a data structure rather than having them hanging around. Another issue: what if you need to add/remove one of them any time in the future? You may say: it will be `null`, but not having it is more meaninful

Comment: Well, no that's not the case here. Those booleans are really just attributes of one entity - the reason why there are so many is because they are describing which allergens there are inside particular kinds of food.

Comment: So, semantically speaking, ask yourself: what `ATTR1`, `ATTR2`, `ATTR3`...`ATTRN` means? Instead, you could have something like: `Map<String, String> allergens` and the values (I'm using kinds of food here, not the allergens): `eggs`/`true`, `fish`/`false`. But right now that you gave more context, in your case, the correct way for modeling this is to have an `ALLERGENS` table and map them into that entity. Then if you have some, it means it's true; otherwise you don't have it (kind of like a convention for `true` and `false`). Moreover...can a food have only 18?

Comment: The [number of allergens is fixed](http://kastner.at/files/Dokumente/LMIV/LMIV-Allergeninfo-KASTNER.pdf). If you're cooking something then it depends on what you use that makes this value true/false. So in any case I would have to store that information in my meal table, right?